# people api, is there a time slice ur sync request

Tags: vba, google-people-api

If I successfully create a contact with createContact and then read all contacts with list connections, this contact is missing.

Is there a time slice until a new contact can be called up?

Or is there a sync command to suspend processing until a request is actually executed?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling createContact and then reading all contacts within the same sub?
There is a fault in excel where API's and data ranges won't refresh while a macro is being run.

If this is the case your solution would be an ontime function, eg:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "ReadAllContacts"
'This will call the procedure ReadAllContacts 15 seconds after it is executed.
```

This is a bug not native to the People API. Bloomberg API does the same thing and requires time between procedures to refresh its data.
You can also change the calculation style of your application to automatic, if it's on a workbook that is, using this command. (Be sure to set it back to `xlCalculationManual` afterwards!

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

yes its in the same sub.

but I think 15 sec's are a very long time?!

I now uses the get request with the returned requestName in a loop with 1 sec wait time. If the get is ok, then i makes the connection.list.

The same problem occurs after a deleteContact followed by connections.list.

(i works with word not with excel)